# If e^itπ  is algebraic , is $t$ a rational number.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I have a elementary question:If e^itπ  is algebraic , is $t$ a rational number.
I do not know whether it is right

Comment: Welcome to MO! This question is not really within the narrow scope of this site. It would seem to fit better on http://math.stackexchange.com a similar site with a broader scope.
Yet in fact something similar (which answers your question) was already asked there http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4323/are-all-algebraic-integers-with-absolute-value-1-roots-of-unity So there you could find more details on this. 

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond–Schneider_theorem

Comment: How is Gelfond--Schneider *directly* relevant here? Without some explanation I have a very hard time seeing this being useful for OP. Actually, I am also a bit dubious what is even meant. 

Comment: @quid: I admit, I read the question too fast...

Comment: @Alain Valette: Thank you for the reply, this explains it. 

Answer (score 1):

The question as stated is very easy to answer. If the question was really intended to be asked about algebraic integers, then there is still a relatively simple direct example to show that the answer is "no". The question about algebraic integers is well-studied, with a substantial literature and the example that follows is one easy instance:

If we take any real algebraic integer $s$ with $0 < s <1,$ then, $t = s + i \sqrt{1-s^{2}}$ is an algebraic integer which lies on the unit circle. Now apply this with $s = \sqrt{2}-1.$ Note that $t$ generates a degree $4$ extension of the rationals. If $t$ were a primitive $m$-th root of unity, we would have $\phi(m) = 4$ so that $m = 8.$ Hence $t$ would be a primitive $8$-th root of unity, but it is not, as each primitive $8$-th root of unity has real part $\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$

Comment: Which question is "this question"? For the one asked on *this* site it might be still simpler to consider $(3 + 4i)/5$; which is mentioned *in the question on math.SE*. Discussions of questions asked on *other* sites in answers here seem off-topic.    

Comment: OK, I thought that the question had been asked about algebraic integers, not algebraic numbers. For algebraic numbers the question is much easier, of course. As a matter of general principle, I feel that a person who asks a reasonable question on here deserves a constructive response, and I try to answer questions in that way. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I definitely prefer your answer over the first comment (meanwhile delted) or the link to Gelfond--Schneider. (updated)